# Cannot match spamassassin custom regex rule

Tags: postfix-mta, mail-server, spamassassin

I want to match this pattern in my spamassassin's filtering rules:

```
Password archivio: 666


Per conto di:
```

There is a space after di: and the number can be of undefined digits.
in my custom.cf I have created this rule

```
body CUSTOM_SPAM_RULE   /Password\sarchivio:\s\d+\n\n\nPer\sconto\sdi:\s/
score CUSTOM_SPAM_RULE  99.9
describe CUSTOM_SPAM_RULE       Regola di spam custom
```

I have checked the regex with an online tool and is working, you can check it here https://regex101.com/r/O3BfDK/1 but I have no hits in my mail gateway, the server side configuration is working cause if I change the rule to a simple regex like \test\ and send an email with a body containing test, I can clearly watch the hits. So, what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok found it in official spamassassin's documentation

> **Rawbody rules** Rawbody rules allow you to search the body of the email without certain kinds of preprocessing that SA normally does
> before trying body rules. In particular HTML tags won't be stripped
> and line breaks will still be present. This allows you to create rules
> searching for HTML tags or HTML comments that are signs of spam or
> nonspam, or particular patterns of line-break.

so the correct rule becomes

```
rawbody CUSTOM_SPAM_RULE   /Password\sarchivio:\s\d+\n\n\nPer\sconto\sdi:\s/
score CUSTOM_SPAM_RULE  99.9
describe CUSTOM_SPAM_RULE       Regola di spam custom
```

Comment: I have a similar filter and it does not work. It is as if the regex would not run at all. It is not clear either if it is a multiline regex or not, I mean with m flag it should cover the \n with \s. I am not sure either if I can use flags or not.

Comment: On an online regex testing tool it matches. I have no idea what's wrong, in theory everything is properly set. :S

Comment: Turned out I have to set it on GUI without // and flags. It is global, multiline and ignorecase by default.